# MySQL in XAMPP doesn't work, I didn't change anything

Tags: mysql, xampp

Iam working on local server for 2 years. Yesterday I started my XAMPP, server worked but Mysql is not working. I didn't change anything.

Any help bellow error log.

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-12-10 22:43:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-12-10 22:43:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-12-10 22:43:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-12-10 22:43:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-12-10 22:43:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-12-10 22:43:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-12-10 22:43:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-12-10 22:43:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-12-10 22:43:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-12-10 22:43:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'G:\xampp New\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-12-10 22:43:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'G:\xampp New\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-12-10 22:43:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 79421478; transaction id 771050
2019-12-10 22:43:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from G:\xampp New\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-12-10 22:43:36 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-12-10 22:43:36 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: May be a Windows OS update caused the pblm. Is Windows updated on last shutdown? I had also experienced this before 4 months. I installed mysql 8.0 seperately. Tillnow its working fine.

Comment: I will try that. thank you

Comment: did u figure out the pblm